# Closing error window

Tags: gvim, vim-windows, filetype-python

When I run yapf on my code, an error page appears, rightly showing the error I have in the code. How on earth do I close this window and go back to my code? `:lclose` doesn't work. `:close` closed the whole tab, including my code. `:q` closes the whole tab again. How can I close this error tab?

I am running gVim 8.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `:cclose`?

Comment: can you show a screenshot of the error pane that has been opened (since it seems that neither `:lclose` nor  `:cclose` work for you).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>It's a`quickfix` window, and you can close it with the command `:cclose`.</strike>

The above is rubbish, and I apologise for answering too hastily.

All the yapf plugins I found seem to work by replacing your entire file contents with the result of running the yapf command. (This is expected functionality, as yapf is a code formatter.)

You should be able to go back simply by pressing `u` to undo the changes that the command you ran has made to your code.

Comment: It doesn't close the window :( nothing happens when I do <code>:cclose</code>
Any idea why?

Comment: @Ali It's because it's not a `quickfix` window! See my edited answer for a solution that is more likely to work. If it *doesn't* work, then let me know what plugin or command you're using to invoke yapf from Vim.

Comment: Thanks @Rich. It works fine. You saved me a lot of headache. Thank you very much.